# Best data structure for a collection of data with only changes between each iteration

Tags: java, performance, signal-processing

I am implementing Short time fourier transform with a 70% overlap between each frame (256 samples per frame).since between each iteration only around the first 75 samples change i am wounding what is the best way to implement this in JAVA. meaning what is the quickest way to delete the first 70 samples and append the new 70 samples in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a job for a Circular Buffer.

Here is a simple implementation to copy/paste: [Circular Array List for Java](http://www.museful.net/2012/software-development/circulararraylist-for-java)

And here is one from the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/): [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of `Queue` collection, which allows you to remove the oldest elements (at the top of the queue) and add new ones to the end.

A [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a possible implementation of `Queue` that would work. Use `add` or `addAll` to add elements to the end and `remove` to remove the first element from the list.

If you want to create your own custom data structure, a cyclic queue of limited length (256 in your case) would be ideal. Such a queue would overwrite old samples each time you append new samples. I didn't find an existing such data structure in the Java APIs.

EDIT : You didn't specify what type of data each sample holds. If it's a primitive - double - as suggested in maaartinus's comment, you'd probably do better not using Java's standard collections, since they involve boxing overhead when used for storing primitives. Instead, you can, as suggested in the privious paragraph, create your own cyclic queue. As maaartinus suggested, it can be backed by an array, `double[256]`, which would be quite efficient.

Comment: `LinkedList` is one of the most terrible data structures ever. While it's good in theory, the cases when it really makes sense are rare. Especially here, when the OP needs to deal with primitives, the overhead of *any collection* is too high when compared to a `new double[256]` cyclic buffer (pretty easy to implement).

Comment: @maaartinus I didn't know each sample is a double. I thought it was some non-primitive object. I agree that a double[256] would be better in this case.

Comment: In a theory, a discrete Fourier Transform needs an arbitrary [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), but real numbers are surely the most common, especially in *signal-processing*.

Comment: It may be easier/faster to use a double[512] instead of dealing with the wraparound that comes with a double[256] (when handling frames of 256 samples).